# Function with generic returns a weird IterableIterator<> type

Tags: typescript

I hava a type

```
type Fruit = {
    name: string;
    color: string;
};
```

and data containing fruits which can have two slightly different formats. The first is

```
const fruits: Fruit[] = [
    {
        name: "Banana",
        color: "yellow",
    },
    {
        name: "Apple",
        color: "green",
    },
];
```

and the second is

```
const fruits2: { entries: Fruit[] } = {
    entries: [
        {
            name: "Banana",
            color: "yellow",
        },
        {
            name: "Apple",
            color: "green",
        },
    ],
};
```

I would like to create a function which takes in an object on any of these two formats and returns it on the first format. In other words:

1. If the function takes in `fruit` it should simply return whatever was passed in.
2. If the function takes in `fruit2` it should "remove" the entries key and return list with type `Fruit[]`

Here is my attempt:

```
function maybeConvertToFormatOne<T extends object>(data: T | { entries: T }): T {
    return "entries" in data ? data.entries : data;
}

const converted = maybeConvertToFormatOne(fruits);
// Expected type: Fruit[]
// Actual type: () => IterableIterator<[number, Fruit]>

const converted2 = maybeConvertToFormatOne(fruits2);
// Expected type: Fruit[]
// Actual type: Fruit[]
```

Where does this `() => IterableIterator<[number, Fruit]>` type come from and how can I fix it?

Comment: it must be a generic function ? or it can be `maybeConvertToFormatOne(data: Fruit[] | { entries: Fruit[] })` ?

Comment: Must be generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [Array.prototpye.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) actually exists.

Write in this way instead.

```
function maybeConvertToFormatOne(data: Fruit[] | { entries: Fruit[] }): Fruit[] {
    return Array.isArray(data) ? data : data.entries;
}
```

I don't see the point of using generics here, but you can change it back if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense that the "entries" collides with this internal name. Your code worked great or the Fruit example, but I need to use generics since in my real case it can be other types as well. When I tried your code with generics it still gave wrong type.

Comment: Edit: Tried again and it work also when using generics. Not sure why it didn't work first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
function maybeConvertToFormatOne<T>(data: T[] | { entries: T[] }) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return data as T[];
    } else {
      return (data as { entries: T }).entries as T[];
    }
  }
```

You must say that your `T` is an array.

Comment: It worked, thank you! By the way, if anyone knows a way to solve it without all these type assertions, please share.

Comment: Yes this is the best I've found in 5 minutes, if someone sees something better, feel free to suggest